# Сommand tox -r doesn't deploy venv python in project

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, tox

I have some project, that on my local pc by windows correct work.
When I copy this project through gitlab on server, I don't see some folders.
So, tox -r command doesn't deploy venv python in project. How can I fix this?
Tox.ini :

```
[tox]
skipsdist = True
envlist = testenv

[testenv]
basepython = python3.7
alwayscopy=true
envdir = venv
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}/framework{:}{toxinidir}/pytest_plugins{:}venv/Lib/site-packages/
    PYTHONIOENCODING = UTF-8

deps =
    attrdict
    Faker==5.0.1
    luhnpy==1.0.0
    mimesis==4.1.2
    pytest==4.4.0
    requests
    selenium==3.141.0
    openpyxl

commands =
    -python`
```

Folder structure:
[image]

Comment: please show us the output of `tox -rvv` from your gitlab instance

Answer (score 0):

Tox utilizes python(3)-venv to create the venv folder.

The venv folder looks different on Windows and Linux. As shown in your screenshot in Windows you have folder `Script` whereas in Linux you have the folder `bin`.
The `tmp` folder is Windows specific and does not exist when creating in Linux.

So this is intended behavior and we don't know what you are trying to achieve.

---

This is how you activate the venv in Windows:

```sh
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

This is how you activate the venv in Linux:

```sh
source venv/bin/activate
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

First line when you are in working directory with the `venv` folder.

Comment: Thank a lot. Now I see. I wrong describe my problem.
When I start my test on server, test trying to find some libs not in folder of project.
When I start conftest in project:
from quack_tools.quack_action import quack_action
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'quack_action' from 'quack_tools.quack_action' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/quack_tools/quack_action/__init__.py)
But conftest should search in home/gitlab-unner/zonatelecom/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/quack_tools

Answer (score 0):

I find problem. I needed to add in yml file command source /home/gitlab-runner/xxx/venv/bin/activate